# How to disable double-precision math while compiling with GCC or/and IAR?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, embedded, arm

My embedded C code is running on `Cortex M4F` which has single precision `FPU`. I am concerned about how often the compiler puts software-based double-precision math in places like

**

```
float_var1 = 3.0 * int_var / float_var_2;
(3.0 instead of 3.0f)
```

**

I am afraid that I would miss some of these double constants. How can I locate all occurrences of slower double-precision math? Disabling double-precision or generating an error/warning with either **sourcery GCC or IAR** would do it.

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 13):

> How can I locate all occurrences of slower double-precision math?
> Disabling double-precision or generating an error/warning with either
> sourcery GCC or IAR would do it.

`-Wdouble-promotion` does exactly what you want, see the doc, under [Warning Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). The example in the doc is quite similar to yours by the way.

Here is basically your example:

```
float f(int int_var, float float_var_2) {
  return 3.0 * int_var / float_var_2;
}
```

And here is what happens when I pass the `-Wdouble-promotion` flag to gcc:

> gcc -c -Wdouble-promotion float.c
> float.c: In function ‘f’:
> float.c:2:24: warning: implicit conversion from ‘float’ to ‘double’ to match other operand of binary expression [-Wdouble-promotion]

If you pass the `-Werror` flag as well, you can turn all warnings into errors. If that is too strict, you can selectively turn warnings into errors by passing `-Werror=foo`, see the docs under [Warning Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: When passing `-Werror`, use it wisely: instead of blindly turning all warnings into errors, target the specific ones: `-Werror=double-promotion`. Otherwise your program will likely stop compiling with a new compiler version.

Answer (score 7):

gcc has an [optimization option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) `-fsingle-precision-constant` that treats ordinary floating point constants as single precision:

> -fsingle-precision-constant
>
> Treat floating-point constants as single precision instead of implicitly converting them to double-precision constants.

Answer (score 3):

As a quick solution, try to follow these steps:

1. Append to every float constant by the suffix f: 1.3f, 3.1415f, and so on.
2. Use only `float` variables.
    Even in the case that the compiler made intermediate high precition calculations,
    the final result will be trunctated to the precition of `float`.
3. Take in account that the types `float`, `double` and `long double`,
    all they are trying to follow the rules performed by the
    floating-point standard ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559.
    Take a look to: [Floating point standard for C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1605.pdf)
    The type `float` is intended to be `single floating-point`,
    the type `double` is intended to be `double floating-point`,
    and the type `long double` it intended to be `extended precistion floating-point`.
4. Make `(float)` cast in relevant parts of your calculations.
5. Use functions of `<math.h>` with suffix "f",
    which are intended to accept and return values of type `float`.

However, all the earlier recipes are only recommendations.
Sometimes the compiler makes intermediate calculations in the precition of `long double`.
This information can be retrieved from macros existing in the `<float.h>` header.
For example:

```
   FLT_EVAL_METHOD  // gives information about the method used in intermediate evaluations  
   FLT_ROUNDS       // gives information about the rounding method
```

Perhaps, to fine tune the behaviour of floating-point evaluations, you will have to go deeper inside the options of your particular compiler.

Comment: This is not a "quick solution". OP asked the question to help him avoid all (or some of) this trouble.

Comment: Agreed. It seems an old question. Cannot downvote my own answer.

Comment: Haha, never heard of anyone wanted to downvote their own answer.  That would be unnecessary since your answer is quite good.  Those are all very valuable ways that people should be handling floats in their own code.